# OOxml or Office OpenXML C# - export from DataTable to excel boolean data type causes repair excel

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am exporting C# DataTable data to excel, I am getting excel repair error for boolean datatype column. following is code I am using for boolean datatype.

```
var exception = true;
var cellDataRow = new Cell();                    
cellDataRow.CellValue = new CellValue(BooleanValue.FromBoolean(exception));                                   cellDataRow.DataType = CellValues.Boolean;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **0 or 1** to represent **false or true** respectively.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = null;

                try
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var excel = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, true))
                        {
                            workbookPart = excel.AddWorkbookPart();
                            workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                            uint sheetId = 1;
                            excel.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();
                            Sheets sheets = excel.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();

                            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

                            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                            {
                                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                                dataTable.TableName = "Table" + (i + 1).ToString();

                                dataTable.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
                                dataTable.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
                                dataTable.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));
                                dataTable.Columns.Add("Column4", typeof(string));
                                dataTable.Columns.Add("Column5", typeof(string));

                                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                                {
                                    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                                    for (int k = 0; k < dataTable.Columns.Count; k++)
                                        dataRow[k] = 0; // or 1

                                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                                }

                                dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables.Count; i++)
                            {
                                string relationshipId = "rId" + (i + 1).ToString();
                                WorksheetPart wSheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>(relationshipId);
                                string sheetName = dataSet.Tables[i].TableName;
                                Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = sheetName };
                                sheets.Append(sheet);

                                Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet();

                                wSheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;

                                SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
                                worksheet.Append(sheetData);

                                string[] excelColumns = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };

                                for (int l = 0; l < dataSet.Tables[i].Rows.Count; l++)
                                {
                                    for (int m = 0; m < dataSet.Tables[i].Columns.Count; m++)
                                    {
                                        AddToCell(sheetData, Convert.ToUInt32(l + 1), excelColumns[m], CellValues.Boolean, Convert.ToString(dataSet.Tables[i].Rows[l][m]));
                                    }
                                }

                                sheetId++;
                            }

                            excel.Close();
                        }

                        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "MultipleWorkSheet.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                        memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
                        fileStream.Close();
                        memoryStream.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // logging, etc.
            }
        }

        private static void AddToCell(SheetData sheetData, UInt32 uint32rowIndex, string strColumnName, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue<CellValues> CellDataType, string strCellValue)
        {
            Row row = new Row() { RowIndex = uint32rowIndex };
            Cell cell = new Cell();

            cell = new Cell();
            cell.CellReference = strColumnName + row.RowIndex.ToString();
            cell.DataType = CellDataType;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(strCellValue);
            row.AppendChild(cell);

            sheetData.Append(row);
        }
    }
}
```